# Recently occurring geopandas import error

Tags: python, geopandas

I have been using `geopandas` for a while now and have never seen this error. Since last few weeks, I am noticing a `geopandas` import error. Did anything change recently with the package? What does keyerror `MISSING` mean?

Package details:

```
Name: geopandas
Version: 0.9.0
Summary: Geographic pandas extensions
Home-page: http://geopandas.org
Author: GeoPandas contributors
Author-email: kjordahl@alum.mit.edu
License: BSD


Name: pygeos
Version: 0.9
Summary: GEOS wrapped in numpy ufuncs
Home-page: https://github.com/pygeos/pygeos
Author: Casper van der Wel
Author-email: caspervdw@gmail.com
License: BSD 3-Clause


Traceback (most recent call last)

KeyError
<ipython-input-4-6f0517744ee1> in <module>
     38 #import gdal as gdal
     39 #from osgeo import ogr
---> 40 import geopandas as gpd
     41 from shapely.geometry import Point
     42 from shapely.geometry import Polygon

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/geopandas/__init__.py in <module>
      1 from geopandas._config import options  # noqa
      2 
----> 3 from geopandas.geoseries import GeoSeries  # noqa
      4 from geopandas.geodataframe import GeoDataFrame  # noqa
      5 from geopandas.a
~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/geopandas/_vectorized.py in <module>
 
~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/geopandas/_vectorized.py in <dictcomp>(.0)
     37 
     38 if compat.USE_PYGEOS:
---> 39     type_mapping = {p.value: _names[p.name] for p in pygeos.GeometryType}
     40     geometry_type_ids = list(type_mapping.keys())
     41     geometry_type_values = np.array(list(type_mapping.values()), dtype=object)

KeyError: 'MISSING'
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a compatibility issue with older GeoPandas (0.8.1 and older) and newer pygeos (0.9). Make sure you use both packages in their latest versions (0.9.0 for both at this moment).

Comment: I ran `pip uninstall geopandas` and `pip install --upgrade geopandas==0.9.0` and am now running into a different error. `AttributeError: partially initialized module 'geopandas' has no attribute '_compat' (most likely due to a circular import)`

Comment: That is strange. Anyway, since you are using `conda` to manage environments I would strongly recommend using it to install geopandas and its dependencies as well. `conda install -c conda-forge geopandas=0.9.0`